# In Google Sheets, how can I remove similar (but not duplicate) strings from the same column?

Tags: google-sheets, fuzzy-comparison

In Google Sheets, I have a column which is a list of company names, all within the same column. The problem is that some of them are repeated with slight differences. For example:

```
Company 1 Limited    
Company 1 Ltd    
Company 2    
Company 3 Group    
Company 3    
Company 4    
Company 5 p.l.c    
Company 5 plc
```

Is there a way I can delete the similar (e.g. Company 1 "Ltd" vs Company 1 "Limited" entries to end up with a list like this?

```
Company 1 Ltd
Company 2
Company 3 Group
Company 4
Company 5 plc
```

I don't have a preference between words like 'Ltd' or 'Limited', or whether 'group' is present or not. I would just like to reduce, as much as possible, these similar double entries. I've come across fuzzylookup but my understanding is that it only works between two ranges.

The easiest thing for me to do would be to strip down the company names to a standard form by removing "Ltd" and "limited" with find and replace, and then remove the duplicates, but I would rather not go down this path as I would like to retain something following the company name. Keep in mind that the column contains company names which vary in string length. "Company X" is used in this case for demonstration purposes.

Sample here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u2XDzKR09Ri_hR9FXxs9OwRswEKDvhlXCaLb1w-rhSc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think the criteria for what amounts to "similar" is not clear. Is it possible to clarify this a bit more?

Comment: @lamblichus - Thanks for your response. Yes, apologies. For example, say I have two entries: "Google Limited" and "Google Ltd". They are very similar because of the truncation of "Limited" and I would like to have a list where only one of those entries is retained. Similarity would be defined as 'Company' + 'Limited' vs. 'Ltd', or 'Company' + 'p.l.c.' vs. 'plc'. In other words, I want to identify all the pairs of similar entries and then delete accordingly (i.e. delete one of the similar entries). Does that help?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're trying to accomplish, but I don't think there are clear rules which we can transmit to a formula. A clear rule would be: `two items are "similar" if all its words barring the last one are the same, and the last word starts with the same letter`. That is something that we can define via formula. But if we don't clarify the criteria to that level, we cannot do that, it's too vague.

Comment: @lamblichus - OK - now I see what you mean. Thanks for your patience. I would say what you specified is more or less what I'm after. So the first n words must be the same, but then there is a word at the end which causes the two items to differ (in this case, 'limited' vs 'ltd', or 'plc' vs 'p.l.c.'). In most cases it is indeed the case that they start with the same letter, but the final word is truncated. It doesn't matter to me which one is removed, as long as I only retain one of those entries. Does this clarify the issue?

Comment: This is an instance where *realistic sample data* is required in order to write anything that would stand a change of being effective against your actual data. That is, while a formula or script could be written around your dummy data, it is unlikely to hold up with your actual data. Consider sharing realistic data in your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: @NickB `In most cases it is indeed the case that they start with the same letter`. "Most" is not enough. Valid criteria ought to apply to all your data.